# Функция преобразования данных JSONB в выражение для использования в запросе

Tags: json, postgresql

Здравствуйте!
Как написать функцию, например convert_json_to_columns, которая преобразовывала данные из формата JSONB так, чтобы можно было использовать выходные параметры как выборку колонок для запроса

select (SELECT convert_json_to_columns('[{ "cmp" : "id", "cmp" : "name", "cmp" : "ean13" }]'::jsonb)) from cmp

чтобы в итоге получилось select cmp.id, cmp.name, cmp.ean13 from cmp

Comment: 1. У вас некорректный JSON, в структуре не может быть 3 поля с одинаковым именем (cmp), попробуйте выполнить приведение этой строки к jsonb и увидите, что возвращается только одно значение. 2. динамическое формирование имен колонок в SQL не возможно в принципе, ни из каких источников. Вот сделать функцию, которая построит запрос как текст и выполнит его, более реально

Comment: Я попробовал сделать так, но SELECT *
FROM   jsonb_to_record(replace(trim(both '[]' from '[{"table":"cmp"},{"cmp":"id"}]'), '},{', ',')::jsonb) AS x("table" text, "cmp" text), но переделать в текст cmp.id и вставить получаемое в запрос не получается. Плюс думаю добавить так, чтобы в цикле обрабатывались входящие данные

Comment: Есть идеи как сделать функцию, которая построит запрос как текст и выполнит его?

Comment: Используйте execute https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12780275/dynamic-sql-query-in-postgres

Comment: Спасибо за ссылку помогло. Еще вопрос: для использования условия, преобразованного из массива JSONB я попробовал использовать SELECT * FROM jsonb_to_record(replace(trim(both '[]' from '[{"table":"cmp"},{"cmp":"id"}]'), '},{', ',')::jsonb) AS x("table" text, "cmp" text) ,но получается таблица, Но как использовать https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31713182/in-postgresql-how-can-i-unwrap-a-json-string-to-text чтобы получить в итоге cmp.id?

Comment: читаете курсором из этого запроса и добавляете поля к тексту запроса по одному

Comment: С курсорами раньше не работал, не подскажете, как грамотно написать в этой ситуации, если не сложно

Comment: Как из массива json ["cmp","id","cmp","name"] выбрать первое значение?

Comment: никак. ваша проблема в том, что это не JSON, а просто строка данных похожая по формату, но не отвечающая стандартам json. и функций для нормальной работы с такой строкой просто не существует (как я и заметил в самом первом комментарии). разве что писать какие нибудь регулярные выражения, без 100% гарантии результата